# Include method implementation in the interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which will be implemented by multiple classes:

```js
interface I {
  readonly id: string;
  process(): void;
}
```

I would like to be able to pass `id` through a constructor such as:

```js
class A implements I {...}
let a: A = {id: "my_id"} // or new A("my_id");
```

I don't want to repeat the implementation of the default constructor in every implementation class, like:

```js
class A implements I {
  constructor(id: string){ this.id = id }
}
```

I tried putting the implementation of the constructor in the interface itself, but but a "cannot find `id`" error.

Is it possible to do in TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it's not possible [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693398/12219726).

you could do something like this however:

```js
interface IMyInterface {
    readonly id: string;
    process(): void;
}

class ParentClass {
    id: string;
    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class SubClassOne extends ParentClass implements IMyInterface {
    process(): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}
class SubClassTwo extends ParentClass implements IMyInterface {
    process(): void {
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
}

const myclassOne = new SubClassOne('123');
const myclassTwo = new SubClassTwo('123');
```